# Is there a way to perform an index access to an instance of a struct?

Tags: rust

Is there a way to perform an index access to an instance of a struct like this:

```
struct MyStruct {
    // ...
}

impl MyStruct {
    // ...    
}

fn main() {
    let s = MyStruct::new();
    s["something"] = 533; // This is what I need
}
```

Comment: Answerers might be able to give more concrete examples if you explain what you want `s["something"] = 533` to *do*. Otherwise, we will just be able to show you the syntax and traits you will need to implement.

Comment: @Shepmaster, you don't understand what `s["something"] = 533` does?

Comment: There's not enough context presented to truly sure what you want. It has the possibility of doing *anything Rust can do* (writing a file, sending data over the network, `panic`ing, so on) as long as in the end it returns a mutable reference to an integral variable (and it's not clear if you'd want a 16-, 32- or 64-bit value, but that's just being pedantic).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) and [`IndexMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html) traits.

```
use std::ops::{Index, IndexMut};

struct Foo {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl Index<&'_ str> for Foo {
    type Output = i32;
    fn index(&self, s: &str) -> &i32 {
        match s {
            "x" => &self.x,
            "y" => &self.y,
            _ => panic!("unknown field: {}", s),
        }
    }
}

impl IndexMut<&'_ str> for Foo {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, s: &str) -> &mut i32 {
        match s {
            "x" => &mut self.x,
            "y" => &mut self.y,
            _ => panic!("unknown field: {}", s),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo { x: 0, y: 0 };

    foo["y"] += 2;
    println!("x: {}", foo["x"]);
    println!("y: {}", foo["y"]);
}
```

It prints:

```
x: 0
y: 2
```

Comment: do I have to use them both?

Comment: If you want both operations, yes.

Comment: So how is `foo['y']` it beneficial  from `f.y`? We have `f.y` anyway, right? But what I want is to have `foo['y']` **only** and not to able to do `f.y` at all.

Comment: It was just an example; there's no reason that the value retrieved with the index has to be a field of a struct. E.g. `HashMap` supports indexing with whatever it's key type is, including `&str`, say `map: HashMap<&str, u32>`, `let value: u32 = map["foo"];`.

Comment: You probably don't understand my question. What does it have to do with HashMap as I want to use my own struct, not HashMap or BTreeMap **instead**?

Comment: @dbaupp is simply using `HashMap` as an example of another way that the `Index(Mut)` trait is implemented. Your only requirement is to return a (mutable) reference to the type `Index::Output`. How you implement that logic is *completely up to you*. Your original example is a bit sparse, so we are just guessing at possible things that you might find useful.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp, I understand the question you asked perfectly (note, the one you actually asked isn't necessarily the one you *wanted* to ask :) ), and was giving a working example of using the traits. You just need to change the contents of the struct and the contents of the implementations to suit your use case. `HashMap` is just a custom struct defined in `std` that implements those traits, it hasn't got anything special and so is just another example of using those traits to get the `[]` notation.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid the mostly identical code in `Index` and `IndexMut`?
I.e. something like calling `self.index` from `self.index_mut`? I have a relatively big struct and there it kind of sucks to have the big `match` case twice.

Answer (score 7):

You want to use the [`Index` trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) (and its pair [`IndexMut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html)):

```rust
use std::ops::Index;

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Foo;
struct Bar;

impl Index<Bar> for Foo {
    type Output = Foo;

    fn index<'a>(&'a self, _index: Bar) -> &'a Foo {
        println!("Indexing!");
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    Foo[Bar];
}
```

Comment: That's copy-paste from the documentation, how is it related to my question? I mean, how can I adopt it for my case where the index type is a string?

Comment: It is indeed copy-paste; why would I rewrite a perfectly serviceable example when the Rust documentation already provides it? I copied it here in case the link breaks over time. If you aren't able to translate from the examples in the documentation to your specific case, then you should have linked to the docs in your original question and asked a specific question about the part you are having trouble with.

Comment: What are you trying to convince me in?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem if the fields in `MyStruct` are not homogeneous in their type (e.g. not all `i32`). Then `Index`/`IndexMut` will be a bit trickier to use. You'd be in [`core::any::Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/core/any/index.html) land with reflection and trait objects and would use something like [`bevy_reflect`](https://docs.rs/bevy_reflect/latest/bevy_reflect/).

Alternatively, instead of `Index`/`IndexMut` where you're looking to get a ref or ref mut to a node, you could try `serde::Serialize`/`serde::Deserialize` as a means of accessing tme. That solves your type issue. Using your code from the question, below is the complete implementation using [miniconf](https://crates.io/crates/miniconf).

The trait supports accessing nodes by `usize` numeric field index or by `&str` field name. It works fine for deeper hierarchies, arrays and nested structs (the example below already shows some of that) and supports any `serde` backend (showing JSON for convenience here).

```rust
use miniconf::{JsonCoreSlash, Miniconf};

#[derive(Miniconf)]
struct MyStruct {
    something: i32,

    #[miniconf(defer(2))]
    other: [Option<u8>; 10],
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = MyStruct {
        something: 99,
        other: [Some(3); 10],
    };
    
    s.set_json("/something", b"533").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(s.something, 533);

    s.set_json("/other/4", b"21").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(s.other[4], Some(21));
}
```

Similar questions have been asked under:

- [How to index struct values of different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73675252/how-to-index-struct-values-of-different-types)
- [Address table to access heterogeneous struct fields by their index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69006039/address-table-to-access-heterogeneous-struct-fields-by-their-index)

Comment: Where did you find out about this crate, miniconf?