# What trait do I need to implement to provide the [index]= operation?

Tags: rust, traits

I want to implement a Rust struct that provides the `[index]=` operation.

For example

```
foo[bar] = zot
```

What trait does `foo` need to implement here?  Is it perhaps some combination of `std::ops`?

Comment: I believe you are looking for [Index](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) or [IndexMut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html)

Comment: @squiguy Going to make that an answer?

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Is there a way to perform an index access to an instance of a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28126735/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Hi.  I implemented both of those, but it didn't let me do []=.  I am just learning Rust, so probably I am missing an important concept here.  IndexMut certainly *sounds* like what I need...

Comment: @user1902291 Please [edit] your question with more prose to describe what you expect `foo[bar] = zot` to *do*, as well as any attempts you've made, what you expect them to do, what they do, etc.

Comment: Hi @Shepmaster.  Yes I believe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126735/is-there-a-way-to-perform-an-index-access-to-an-instance-of-a-struct asks the same question.  Thanks

Comment: @user1902291 so you'd be comfortable marking this as a duplicate?

Comment: Sure.  Thank you