# Is there a way to index vectors from 1 in Rust?

Tags: vector, rust

I'm implementing a binary heap, and in other languages, it's most convenient to do so by storing an internal array, but set the first element of this array to `null` and ignore it. This way, if a node is located at index `i`, its children will always be located at `i * 2` and `i * 2 + 1`.

This no longer works if index 0 is used, because 0 * 2 = 0. However, in Rust, there is no `null`, so I would have to use `Vec<Option<MyHeapItem>>` instead of `Vec<MyHeapItem>`, which makes everything more cumbersome.

So my question is, is there a way to customize `Vec<T>` so that index 1 refers to the first element?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Is there a way to perform an index access to an instance of a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28126735/155423) and [How do I implement a trait I don't own for a type I don't own?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25413201/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks, this did answer my question.

Comment: You can just also `i * 2 + 1` and `i * 2 + 2` instead for the child indices?

Comment: @Zeta oops, maybe I didn't get enough sleep last night

Comment: For future searchers, explicitly stating the fusion of the two duplicates: No, you cannot change how a `Vec` is indexed, but you can create a *newtype* around a `Vec` and implement `Index` / `IndexMut` for that type however you'd like.

Comment: @laptou I accidentally a word in my comment too, so I probably didn't get enough sleep last night either... :D