# Accessing struct field by a given string

Tags: struct, rust

Assume we have a `Person` struct and a `PersonName` struct that used by a field, like the following:

```rust
struct Person {
    name: PersonName,
    age: u8,
}

struct PersonName {
    name: String,
    middle_name: Option<String>,
    surname: Option<String>,
}
```

Create the struct:

```rust
let foo = Person { name: PersonName{name: String::from("bar"), middle_name: None, surname: String::from("baz") }, age: 16u8 };
```

How can I use this string to gain access to the struct field specified in it?

```rust
let foo_surname = eval("name.surname") // returns "baz"
```

```rust
// struct evaluator returns the value of specific field
// i.e.: field_path: "my_struct_field.sub_field1.sub_sub_field_1"
fn eval(field_path: String) -> ...{}
```

Is there any way to do this without writing a custom evaluator?

Comment: You can do this by creating you own trait and create you own derive macro for this trait. But it is VERY complicated to be described here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this.
Rust is a statically compiled language where this kind of information doesn't existing anymore during the program runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two possible approaches.

If you must return the actual heterogeneous (`u8` vs `String`) data from that `eval()`, you'll need to wrap it in an enum and write a `match` on the `field_path` along the lines of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73676114/22362561

However, in many cases you can get around this by serializing the data to hold the heterogeneous types. Here is a solution using [`miniconf`](https://crates.io/crates/miniconf) (disclaimer: I develop that crate) with `'/'` as the path hierarchy separator and JSON as the serialization format:

```
use miniconf::{JsonCoreSlash, Tree};

#[derive(Tree)]
struct Person {
    #[tree]
    name: PersonName,
    age: u8,
}

#[derive(Tree)]
struct PersonName {
    name: String,
    middle_name: Option<String>,
    surname: Option<String>,
}

impl Person {
    fn eval(&self, key: &str) -> String {
        let mut buf = vec![0; 128];
        let len = self.get_json(key, &mut buf).unwrap();
        buf.truncate(len);
        String::from_utf8(buf).unwrap()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Person {
        name: PersonName {
            name: "bar".into(),
            middle_name: None,
            surname: Some("baz".into()),
        },
        age: 16u8,
    };
    assert_eq!(foo.eval("/name/surname"), "\"baz\"");
    assert_eq!(foo.eval("/age"), "16");
}
```

Note that you can plug in other serialization backends (`ser_raw` comes to mind) and also other path hierarchy separators.

Similar:

- [Address table to access heterogeneous struct fields by their index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69006039/address-table-to-access-heterogeneous-struct-fields-by-their-index)
- [Is there a way to perform an index access to an instance of a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126735/is-there-a-way-to-perform-an-index-access-to-an-instance-of-a-struct)
- [How to index struct values of different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73675252/how-to-index-struct-values-of-different-types)